# How to get "datePublished": value from website source code into JavaScript code for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the "datePublished": value from a website's source code for my chrome extension. I want to put the value in my JavaScript file so I can use the date the website was published. How exactly would I go about doing that?

The code I want to refer to is the following:

```
"datePublished":"2017-09-26T20:04:13Z"
```

How would I get the date into my own code?

Comment: If you haven't done so, you may want to check [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). There are limitations, permissions and [security considerations](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#security-considerations) that you should also look into.

Answer (score 0):

**Grab the text of the DOM node and use Regex.**

```
var element = document.getElementById("someIDcontainingThatString");
var date = element.innerText.search(/"datePublished":"(.+)"/);
```

[String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to web development, but what exactly would go in the place of "someIDcontainingThatString"?

Comment: Without seeing the actual page, I don't know. The goal is to get a reference to the HTML element that contains the text you're searching. It could also be a parent tag. Find the text in the source and work "upwards" until you find a tag with an ID. Put that ID in this code, then call `console.log(date)` and you should have the data you seek.